# How to return file contents from controller?

Tags: python, flask, openapi, swagger-codegen, connexion

I'm trying to return the contents of an image file via a Python Connexion application generated from an OpenAPI v2 spec file using swagger-codegen and the python-flask language setting. In my controller module, I simply do the following:

```
def file_contents_get(file_id):
    file = app.datastore.get_instance().get_file(file_id)
    with open(file.path, "rb") as f:
        return f.read()
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

What is the proper way to return a file's contents? Note that I don't want the file as an attachment but rather inline.

Comment: So it looks like this was an issue in my API spec where I was describing the produceable content types as "image/gif", "image/jpg", and "image/png". I guess I didn't understand how this really worked, but when I changed the only possible content type to "application/octet-stream", it began to work as I wanted.

Comment: Would you mind posting your final solution? I'm currently running into exactly the same issues.